# How to make sure a member function is called once

Tags: c++, boost, c++11

Let's say I have a list of objects called foo. How can I make sure that when the first foo is created the member init() is called but only once. Also how do I make sure when the last object is destroyed the member quit() is called but only once.

I know that c++11 has std::call_once and for c++03 boost has boost::call_once.

My first attempt looks like this, but the quitting part is obviously wrong:

```
class foo
{
public:

    foo() { init(); }

    ~foo() 
    {
        // this is wrong
        quit();
    }

private:

    void init()
    {
        static boost::once_flag flag = BOOST_ONCE_INIT;
        boost::call_once( flag, [] () { /* init something */ }  );
    }

    void quit()
    {
        static boost::once_flag flag = BOOST_ONCE_INIT;
        boost::call_once( flag, [] () { /* quit something */ } );
    }
};
```

Is there a way to make it this correct by just relying on the c++ facilities?

Here a small addition to what I'm actually trying do. I'm trying to wrap an SDL window inside a c++ class and would like to call SDL_Init() and SDL_Quit and the appropriate time.
My first try is here: http://pastebin.com/Y9X0UwUB

Comment: `call_once` is for multiple threads to attempt to call a function and have only one of them actually succeed in calling it.

Comment: Can you expand more on what `init()` does and what `foo` represents? There are equally viable solutions for this but the best way to model it depends on your situation.

Comment: @sftrabbit - `call_once` works fine for a single-threaded application, too. With a bit more overhead than might otherwise be possible, though.

Comment: @GManNickG I'm trying to create a SDL wrapper which contains a SDL Window. Before the first window is created I need to call SDL_Init and when the last window is destroyed I like to call SDL_Quit. My first draft is here: http://pastebin.com/Y9X0UwUB

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you want these methods to be `static`, and then also maintain a private static count of the number of live objects, which is incremented/decremented and checked in the constructor(s) and destructor.

Obviously, if this is a multi-threaded app, you'll need some form of synchronization.

Comment: Why would static a static method help? Isn't the once_flag enough?

Comment: @chhenning: I guess it doesn't matter whether the init/quit methods are static, but they sound like they need to perform actions that aren't associated with any specific class instance, so it would make sense to declare them static (in order to document intent).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new class that calls the init function on construction and the quit function on destruction, and then make all instances of your class receive a shared_ptr to an instance of that class upon construction.

```
class foo_init_quit {
    public:
      foo_init_quit(){init();}
      ~foo_init_quit(){quit();}
};

std::vector<foo> do_something() {
    auto init_quit = make_shared<foo_init_quit>();
    std::vector<foo> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(init_quit);
    //...
    return vec;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking along those lines.  Probably makes a great way to call quit(), but init() wouldn't work because the shared_ptr would supposedly not be initialized.  Would still need some stuff there.  I think there's probably an interesting hack here though.

Comment: @CrazyEddie Well, he didn't say what the init function was supposed to do so I thought it didn't require an instance of foo to work.

Comment: @Cubic: Could you provide a working code snippet. I cannot make your code compile. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
struct Funkay
{
    Funkay() : { ++count; init(); }
    ~Funkay() { --count; quit(); }

private:
    static size_t count;
    void init() { if (count == 1) ???; }
    void quit() { if (count == 0) ???; }
};
size_t Funkay::count = 0;
```

Comment: If the class is copyable/movable then there are likely to be a lot more decrements than increments.